# Responsive Twitter embeds

Tags: css, html, twitter

Earlier I could use the code below to make the Twitter embeds responsive:

```
            iframe[id^='twitter-widget-'] { width: 100% }
```

However this no longer works. I've tried different things, but none would work. Does anyone have a newer fix for this?

You can see it in work here: http://musik.dk/samsmith/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 #twitter-widget-1 {
      width:100%;
 }
```

However the container that the widget sits in has a min-width so it will align itself to that.

```
 <section class="mcl mr350">
```

Comment: That one no longer works. I've inserted it including with an !important, and it doesnt work.

Comment: Strange. I now got it to work. Seems it was a cache-issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS should work:

```
.twitter-tweet {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" title="Twitter Timeline" height="600" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; width: 520px;"></iframe>
```

see the `width: 520px;`

Comment: Did you login to twitter and change the 520px width? 

As far as i can see, the only value constraining your box is the width in the iframe...

Comment: No I did not change it, but I need a flexible (procentage) width otherwise its not responsive.

Comment: You need to remove the width : 520px; or change it to 100% or what ever. Login to twitter dev to change it.